# PDO how to treat param variable that can be empty

Tags: php, pdo

I have a prepared statement and param with variables, but it's possible that some of these variables may be empty and it gives me an error.. how to treat the code to  SKIP the empty param?

CODE:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into account (accountID, firstName, imageURL, sex, cat1) VALUES (:accountID,  :firstName,  :sourcefilename, :sex, :cat1)");

$stmt->execute(array(
                  ':accountID' => $accountID, 
                  ':firstName' => $first_name,
                  ':sourcefilename' => $sourcefilename,
                  ':sex' => $gender,
                  ':cat1' => $cat1));
```

Comment: You should be checking for empty fields first. However, is it because you can't modify the query and the number of values/binds? I'd just use a ternary operator.

Comment: what do you mean by checking for empty field first?   I don't know if the field will contain a value or will be empty... so even if I check if a filed is empty, how do I modify the $stmt? I have to make 1 different stmt for each possibility of empty field ?

Comment: `':field' => !empty($field)? $field : ''`

Comment: ^ --- ^ as I stated in my comment; ternary.

Comment: @u_mulder Pretty neat ternary. I hardly see those in questions/answers.

Comment: And in response about making a different statement... no you just dynmically create the SQL for the statement if you need to go that route for some reason (ie. you dont want to update a field that doesnt have a value present, or you want to let it get the whatever the default is on the table). That of course makes it so that you are potentially building multiple statements (instead of reuisng the same statement) if the input is a collection of items, but that is what it is.